# Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided. at new View MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, mean

So I'm following this guide [MEAN STACK GUIDE](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a878b3c80aca7059c142979/securing-mean-stack-angular-5-web-application-using-passport)

I have encountered an error while on number 2

I can't fix it myself since I'm new in studying mean stack

any help here?

here's the full error by the way

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/app.js:32:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/app.js:21:3
GET /favicon.ico 404 1.584 ms - 1428
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/app.js:32:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/app.js:21:3
GET / 404 0.999 ms - 1428
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/app.js:32:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/angelocolmenares/Desktop/Carwash/mean-secure/app.js:21:3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined any routes in `routes/api.js`. So for now you have `localhost:3000/api` and this one is the only route which is accessible.

Plus you are getting `No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.` error because of line no 31 in `app.js` because you want to render error page when you are hitting `localhost:3000/api/profile`. You don't have any route which matches this route. You can solve it by changing those line to:

```
 // error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
 // set locals, only providing error in development
 res.locals.message = err.message;
 res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};


 // render the error page 
 res.status(err.status || 500)
 res.send({ 'error': 'no route found!' });
});
```

for more details about `render` from express read : [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render)